# Created pdf error message(...file is damaged and could not be repaired)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, pdf, itext

I created a pdf file and sent in an email message. The email is sent fine but to open the pdf, I keep getting the following error: "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired". This is the code.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

```
       Document myDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 20f, 20f, 18f, 20f);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter pWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDoc, ms);

            myDoc.Open();

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.WidthPercentage = 100;
            table.SpacingAfter = 10;

            float[] widths = new float[] { 1f, 2f };
            table.SetWidths(widths);
            table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
            table.SpacingAfter = 30f;

            Font regularFont = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12);
            Font boldFont = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, 1);
            Font headerFont = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18, 1);

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.BorderWidth = 1;

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("HEADER", headerFont));
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; 
            table.AddCell(cell);

            cell.Colspan = 1;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0; 

            cell.Phrase = new Phrase("CONTENT:", boldFont);
            table.AddCell(cell);
            cell.Phrase = new Phrase("content", regularFont);
            table.AddCell(cell);
            myDoc.Add(table);

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

            msg.From = new MailAddress("store@email.com", "CONTENT Report");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("user@email.com"));

            msg.Subject += "Content Report";
            msg.Body += "Message.<br> :)";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            ms.Position = 0;
            msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "test.pdf", "application/x-pdf"));
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("10.1.1.15");
            client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: How big is the file size that is generated?  It might not be flushing the contents to the stream.  Other than that I recommend checking the documentation for `PdfWriter` and checking the examples in detail.  You could also try writing the file locally for debugging purposes.

Comment: @NickLarsen - The pdf is a test file and is just 8B

Comment: @user54197: can you open it locally?  8B sounds pretty small.  As in so small I it couldn't possibly store all the information you have listed.

Comment: @Nick - It was a local test and an email sent to my address. So there is something in the code... do you see anything strange that I am missing in the code?  I can't seem to get it.

Comment: @user54197: I mean instead of emailing it, write it to a file in a cut/paste console app.  Eliminate all of the factors you can until you get to where you can open a file and have it work.  Remove the emailing, save locally and try to open.  If that doesn't work, you've eliminated a possible problem.  From the looks of it, everything is correct with the examples I looked up.

Comment: ok it looks like the process of elimination will work... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You forgot something important:

```
 myDoc.Close();
```

Stick it in right after you make your last change to myDoc.

Comment: I just learned you could also wrap `myDoc` inside a nested `using` statement.  Then when you pass out of the `using` scope for `myDoc`, it will automatically `Close()` the Document for you.  This is probably a better design pattern to use with objects that implement IDisposable.